# Is $HK/K = H/K$, when $H,K \leq G$?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$ with $K$ normal in $G$. Is the factor (quotient) group $HK/K = H/K$?

Here is what I have:

\begin{align*}
HK/K &= \{hkK | h \in H, k \in K\}\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=} \{hK|h \in H\} = H/K
\end{align*}

(1) is the part that I don't think is right. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Your $H/K$ doesn't have the usual meaning when $K$ is not a subgroup of $H$. If it is, then $HK = H$.

Answer (score 3):

The part you marked with (1) is right, **yet** that factor group must be denoted as $\;HK/K\;$ since $\;H/K\;$ has meaning *only* if $\;K\subset H\;$ , which may not be the case.

In fact, one of the isomorphism theorems states that

$$HK/K\cong H/(H\cap K)$$

and it is an easy though nice exercise to show that indeed $\;H\cap K\lhd H\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

For the quotient to have a group structure, $K$ must be normal in $HK$. And another thing: there can be repetitions in $H/K$, so you have to take into account their intersection $H\cap K$.

Comment: I did not think that K being normal in G was relevant (it is part of the question), I have edited the original question.

Comment: @Bungo I edited the answer. Thanks for your comment!